# In R, extract the value of column 1 where subsequent columns are max

Tags: r, max, apply

I have a data.frame containing Time as the first column, then each subsequent column is the concentration of a transcription factor for individual cells, for example:

```
Time = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5) 
Cell1 = c(1,5,10,4,2) 
Cell2 = c(1,5,4,11,5) 
Cell3 = c(1,9,5,9,5)
df = data.frame(Time,Cell1,Cell2,Cell3)
```

Which gets:

```
     Time Cell1 Cell2 Cell3
1    0.1   1     1     1
2    0.2   5     5     9
3    0.3  10     4     5
4    0.4   4    11     9
5    0.5   2     5     5
```

Now, I'm trying to extract the Time at which each cell has the maximum concentration of transcription factor to output something like:

```
Cell1 0.3
Cell2 0.4
Cell3 0.2,0.4
```

Apologies if this is simplistic, I'm new to R and have fumbled about forums for an answer for a while now. I can do it by inquiring about each column individually, but I have hundreds of cells and would have to write a script for each one with my current method:

```
cell1_peak=which(df[2]==max(df[2]));cell1_time=df$Time[cell1_peak]
```

Possible way to use the apply function with my current method and compile all cells for easy export?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your data into a "long" format and then use one of the many aggregation functions in R.

Here are two approaches with "data.table".

First, load the packages required.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
```

Option 1: Keep the data long--more flexible to work with later. (I would prefer this option.) From here, you can use `dcast.data.table` if you wanted to collapse this using `paste` or some other approach.

```
melt(as.data.table(df), id.vars = "Time")[, list(
  Time[value == max(value)]), by = variable]
#    variable  V1
# 1:    Cell1 0.3
# 2:    Cell2 0.4
# 3:    Cell3 0.2
# 4:    Cell3 0.4
```

Option 2: Store the results as a `list` column. Offers more flexibility to work with the data later than using `paste`, but not many people expect a column to be a `list`.

```
melt(as.data.table(df), id.vars = "Time")[, list(
  list(Time[value == max(value)])), by = variable]
#    variable      V1
# 1:    Cell1     0.3
# 2:    Cell2     0.4
# 3:    Cell3 0.2,0.4
```

Comment: Thank-you! I went with your second option as I preferred it to give cells with multiple time points in the same line. I'll make a note of your other option too just in case this causes issues later on. Again, thank-you, very easy explanation with a neat output.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x) 
           df$Time[x %in% max(x)])
#$Cell1
#[1] 0.3

#$Cell2
#[1] 0.4

#$Cell3
#[1] 0.2 0.4
```

Or

```
 apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x)  toString(df$Time[x == max(x)]))
  #Cell1      Cell2      Cell3 
  #"0.3"      "0.4" "0.2, 0.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
apply(df[,-1],2,function(x){
                   paste(df$Time[which(x==max(x))],collapse=",")
                 })
```

gives you this :

```
Cell1     Cell2     Cell3 
"0.3"     "0.4" "0.2,0.4"
```